# Finding number of unique phrases

Tags: r

Wondering how to find out the number of unique phrases in R

For example if I have a data set with the following phrases:

```
data<- c("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy cat", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
```

I want to find the number of unique phrases in this case 2.

Using unique function gives an error.

Any ideas to do this in R?

Thanks!

Comment: `data[!duplicated(data)]` or `unique(data)`

Answer (score 2):

Using below code worked-

```
length(unique(data))
```